# Trabajar de manera vista previa con asp.net en visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando con asp.net en visual studio y quiero ver de manera de vista previa en mi página cargada los cambios que voy a haciendo como me lo deja hacer en otros plataforma como WordPress y esas pero quiero hacer lo mismo con asp.net en visuam studio

Answer (score 0):

En la vista source donde visualizas el html de la paginas aspx puede localizar en la parte inferior izquierda la solapa que permite ver el diseñador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]